# Spring boot jar does not detect beans defined in dependent modules

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have spring boot application which runs perfectly when I run the runnable `Application` class of Spring boot from my Intellij locally.

My module `PRESENT` is dependent on another module `OLDER`. So I added B as a dependency in pom.xml of `PRESENT`.

main parts of my `pom.xml` are :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency for Module OLDER>


<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>               
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

I have few beans in `beans.xml`(in Module PRESENT), so I imported `app-context.xml`(which has all beans for Module OLDER) in `beans.xml`.

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...>
      <import resource="classpath:/app-context.xml"/>
      //more beans
  </beans>
```

I have a Service `ThreadService` in `Module OLDER`, in one of the controllers in `MODULE PRESENT` I have autowired this `ThreadService`. When I run locally it works fine but when I create a jar it does not detect the `app-context.xml` and gives the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:/app-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [messageBeans.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [app-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:235)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:186)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:144)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:100)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:347)
```

I have searched a bit and changed

```
<import resource="classpath:/app-context.xml"/>
```

to

```
<import resource="classpath*:**/app-context.xml"/>
```

now it detects the `app-context.xml` but fails to autowire `ThreadService`.

```
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myHandler': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.x.y.service.ThreadService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at message.objects.Application.main(Application.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not sure why spring-boot is not able to detect the beans.

I have tried the following :

1. Tried adding `@ImportResource("classpath:/beans.xml")` on `my controller` as well as `Application` class.
2. I tried using `repackage`

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>repackage</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Would it be possible that the two beans.xml files clash - only one can be written to a particular location in the jar?

Comment: when I run normally, importing either of  `classpath:/app-context.xml`, `classpath:/beans.xml` as a resource is working fine, I don't think they clash but I am not sure.

Comment: If that can helps, Spring Boot does nothing specific regarding the import of xml configuration: it's jut plain Spring Framework. So you can remove that part from the equation.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: Any solutions to this problem ? @Karthik

Comment: @phoenix no, actually I din't look at it from many days.